# With the help of the TILRP

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, visual

I go to a relatively new university called PUZZLE academy located in California. All the students here are known for being very good puzzle solvers so it isn't surprising that everyone likes to discuss puzzle amongst each other.

One day the university arranged a daytime party. I was dancing with a girl on the dancefloor for quite some time. I wanted to smalltalk with her so I started asking her questions (even though the music was quite loud) but when doing so she didn't reply. Probably because of the loud music, I thought to myself. All of a sudden she took out a paper from her purse containing some images and text. Aah, this must be a puzzle! She wants to be mysterious, I thought to myself. Why not.. let's try this!

---

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

---

**What was she trying to say to me?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Continuing from the excellent observations of @ash4fun, I'd say your friend is urging you to

> SIGN, due to the loud music.

Title:

> TILRP gives us finger names: Thumb, Index, Long, Ring, Pinkie. These aren't maybe the most common names, but they're in order and fit.

Image 1:

> It seems this should be sign language for 'S'. The raised hand looks a bit more like 'A', but they are similar and it is hard to tell; or maybe we go with the lower hand.

Image 2:

> Shows sign language for 'I'.

Image 3:

> Shows sign language for 'G'.

Image 4:

> If we use TILRP as in title, we get sign language for 'N'.

Together this spells:

> SIGN

Comment: Ack, I figured out the TILRP in the title and was just starting an edit. Well done!

Comment: This is indeed the answer I had in mind. Check is yours. Well done!

Answer (score 3):

Partial(?) solution:

Was she perhaps trying to tell you about

> Adaptive isogeometric methods?

Reasoning:

> Each of the first three pictures prominently feature hands, and the story briefly mentions an inability to hear. This suggests that sign language is important.
>
>  In fact, each picture corresponds to a letter fingerspelt in [ASL](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_Sign_Language), giving us the message `AIGM`.
>
>  (In the last picture, consisting of text, the sign for `M` is described. "T", "R", and "L" respectively mean the thumb, ring, and little fingers.)
>
>  Now `AIGM` doesn't seem much of a message, but the first few useful google results showed some scholarly research where the "AIGM algorithm" is used to... [identify hand poses](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/3-540-26415-9_118). Regrettably, the article is paywalled, so I can see none of the article beyond the abstract.
>
>  Now, the first-listed author of this publication is a professor of computer science in a college in California. Thus I think that the academy our characters attend may be **UC Berkeley**.  But this doesn't really answer the question.
>
>  Now I was able to find a few other publications referencing AIGM (one of which had the phrase "adaptive isogeometric methods" for which AIGM is presumably an acronym). However, the above is the only one I found which also referenced hand positions. Thus I think that the solution may involve something specific to this publication.
>
>  The article has three identifying numbers--one DOI, and two ISBNs (one for print, one for online). Respectively:
>  `10.1007/3-540-26415-9_118`
>  `978-3-540-26413-2`
>  `978-3-540-26415-6`
>
>  Now I'm not really sure what to do. Alphanumeric conversions on these numbers don't seem very useful. I'm quite confident that the journal article is important, but anything past that is a bit foggy.

Comment: Great job! You were very close. +1!